# CodeKit stopped "watching" folders for file changes, why?

Tags: javascript, web-applications, sass

I love CodeKit, but for some reason, it stopped "watching" for changes to the files in the folder I placed in there.  I double checked the project configuration to make sure the output paths are correct, but when I make a change to any of the files being watched, CodeKit does nothing -- no minifying, syntax checking, compiling down .scss files to .css.

As the developer suggested to "refresh" CodeKit, I launched the app while holding down shift and sure enough CodeKit opened with no projects.  So I re-added the project, and still, it is not watching the files.  Has anybody ever encountered this with CodeKit?

Comment: I've been having this problem quite frequently now. Have you figured out what's problem? The only way I've found to make it work again is to restart my Mac.

Comment: Are you using Codekit 2?

Comment: I have the same problem. A restart helps at first and then after working for 20 minutes or so it stops watching again. Always used to work great.

Comment: Sorry I can't be of more help.  I upgraded to Codekit 2 and have not experienced this issue since then.

Answer (score 1):

I have experienced a similar issue before and it was because in the codekit project I had included the images folder and I generated a huge amount of .png images.  Every time codekit ran it got  hung up processing the pngs trying to compress them.

Try putting your images folder outside of your codekit project directory and see if that helps.

Comment: Thanks! I was having to restart my computer every time CodeKit decided to stop working until I found this workaround!

Answer (score 0):

I've been having the same problem lately (Version 2.1.9). I haven't managed to figure out the root cause as yet, but I have figured out a way to solve this issue every time it occurs.

Rename your parent folder that contains all of your CodeKit projects. E.g. my HTDocs equivalent folder is called "Sites". In Terminal do this:

```
mv sites sites_temp
mv sites_temp sites
```

The first line will rename your sites folder to sites_temp, and then the second line will do the opposite.

For some reason this works every time for me.

I've written a short blog post on this matter here, but to be honest the above is my go-to solution whenever this problem occurs: http://www.joetannorella.com/codekit-mac-auto-compiling-compass-upon-file-change/